# hover on an element and not affect others with same class name

Tags: jquery, hover, this, mouseover

Hi I'm struggling with something that probably seems simple (and maybe is) but I can't figure out how to only affect the element I'm hovering over when there are other elements with the same class name.

I'm obviously missing something but here is what I'm using and failing as it applies the **.insertAfter()** to all elements called **.item** and not just the one hovered:

```js
$('.item').hover(
   function() {
      $('<div class="testText">TEST</div>').insertAfter('.block' , this);
   }, 
   function() {

   }
);
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  text-align:center;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #000;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"><div class="block"></div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="block"></div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="block"></div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="block"></div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="block"></div></div>
```

I tried adding an **.each()** function and then using **$(this)'hover()** inside but that wasn't the answer either so I really need a little help here to only affect the hovered **.item**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `insertAfter()` does not accept `this` in the second argument as a contextual selector like the jQuery object (`$()`) does, so you are selecting *all* `.block` and calling `insertAfter()` on them.

To work around this you can use `find()` instead:

```js
$('.item').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.block').after('<div class="testText">TEST</div>');
}, function() {
  // I assume you want to remove the content you added here as well...
  $(this).find('.testText').remove();
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #000;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick your snippet appears to work, so I'm just testing it on site and will mark yours as the answer as soon as I confirm :)